# HttpPost return 400 once publish and remote SQL Server but works fine with localdb?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

New to ASP.NET and SQL Server, I read and update a database with `DbContext`. It works fine as long as I debug on localhost and the SQL Server is `localdb`, but when I deploy it and access the SQL Server remotely, I can read the data from the database no problem but when I want to add a new entry using `HttpPost`, this time I get an http error 400.

Here is what I use to update the database:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(ECO obj)
    {
        _db.Items.Add(obj);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }
```

and here is my connection string.. again I can display the entry from the database in a table so I know the connection is working but I can't post.. Any idea?

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=XXXXXXXX;Database=XXXX;trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
   
"RemoteConnection": "Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=XXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXX"
```

Comment: It could be with your new Sql server permissions. Check if the user is allowed  to write, not only to read.

Comment: Please do some reading to understand how to handle and log exceptions in .NET.

Comment: As far as I know, 400 error means bad request, I suggest you could re-check your post request to make sure it contains the right header. Besides, I suggest you could check your IIS settings to make sure there is some restrict policy which will block your client request. Like IP restrict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, In the end as suggested by Serge, I checked the SQL permission and db_datawriter was unchecked. then I had to remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] to make it work. Not a big deal for now, it is just a test.